# How to show $\neg(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P ∧ \neg Q)$ in Fitch?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

How do I show $ \neg (P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P ∧ \neg Q) $ in Fitch-style FOL proof system? I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

Thanks for the help!

(I'm pretty sure this property is called Negative Implication or something like that, if anybody knows that'd also be great)

EDIT: I'm not allowed to use Contradiction Elimination. Sorry for not specifying in original post!

EDIT 2: Apparently am allowed so thanks to Manx for the answer and to everybody else for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\lnot (P\implies Q)\equiv\lnot(\lnot P\lor Q)\equiv \lnot P\land\lnot\lnot Q\equiv \lnot P \land Q$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Quite true; we believe it, but it's not a Fitch-style, natural deduction proof.

Comment: I meant $\lnot (P\implies Q)\equiv\lnot(\lnot P\lor Q)\equiv \lnot\lnot P\land  Q\equiv  P \land \lnot Q$ anyway

Comment: Examining the symbols present in your assumption versus the conclusion, I would probably start thinking about $\to$ elimination and $\land$ introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{0.~~}{\fitch{1.~~\neg(P\to Q)}{\fitch{2.~~\neg P}{\fitch{3.~~P}{4.~~\bot\hspace{10ex}\bot~\text{Intro 2,3}\\5.~~Q\hspace{10ex}\bot~\text{Elim 4}}\\6.~~P\to Q\hspace{6.5ex}\to\text{Intro 3-5}\\7.~~\bot\hspace{13.4ex}\bot~\text{Intro 1,6}}\\8.~~P\hspace{17.2ex}\neg~\text{Intro 2-7}\\\fitch{9.~~Q}{\fitch{10.~~P}{11.~~Q\hspace{11ex}\text{Reit 9}}\\12.~~P\to Q\hspace{5.5ex}\to\text{Intro 10-11}\\13.~~\bot\hspace{12.4ex}\bot~\text{Intro } 1,12}\\14.~~\neg Q\hspace{14.5ex}\neg~\text{Intro 9-13}\\15.~~P\land\neg Q\hspace{9.5ex}\land\text{Intro 8,14}}\\16.~~(1.\to 15.)\hspace{9.5ex}\to\text{Intro 1-15}}$$

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work to format that! So much easier with $\LaTeX$ packages that unfortunately aren't available in MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

Start a subproof, assume $\neg (P \to Q)$, and try to derive $P \land \neg Q$. Then close the subproof and derive your statement using $\to$ Intro

No further hints though until I see some effort on your part...

Answer (score 1):

This is where I would start in a proof outline:
\begin{align*}
&01.\;|\neg(p\to q)\quad\text{Assumption} \\
&02.\;|------\\
&03.\;||\neg p\quad\text{Assumption} \\
&04.\;||------ \\
&05.\;||\vdots \\
&06.\;||\perp \\
&07.\;|\neg\neg p\quad\neg\text{Intro}, 03-06\\
&08.\;|p \quad \neg\text{Elim}, 07\\
&09.\;||q \quad\text{Assumption}\\
&10.\;||------\\
&11.\;||\vdots \\
&12.\;||\perp \\
&13.\;|\neg q\quad \neg\text{Intro}, 09-12\\
&14.\;|p\land\neg q\quad \land\text{Intro}, 08, 13\\
&15.\;(\neg(p\to\neg q))\to(p\land\neg q) \quad \to\text{Intro}, 1-14
\end{align*}
Now the most difficult work is still remaining: getting the $\perp$'s in Lines 06 and 12, which I've represented by the vertical dots in 05 and 11. Are you able to continue?